# overridePendingTransition() is not working in TabActivity

Tags: android, transition, tabactivity, activitygroup

I am using TabActivity for my application. It has 4 tabs.

Tab 1 is a ActivityGroup. It has many child activities. I used overridePendingTransition() to have a transition between activities. But, it does not work for TabActivity. Also i added overridePendingTransition() in onPause() method of TabActivity. But No use.

Can somebody help me out..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code you can't say much how to solve, but im sure the problem is, that you don't call
`overridePendingTransition` right after starting the new activity. 
Yes, RIGHT after starting the activity. Otherwise it will not affect.

So something like this would work like a charm

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Blub.class));
// don't do anything else between those 2 calls
overridePendingTransistion(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
```